# Alike Shortcode using in Custom Shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-query, custom-field, shortcode

I'm using Alike plugin to compare my custom post types, Alike provides shortcode `[alike_link]` to run the procedure and I have created a shortcode to display my custom post type.
In this shortcode I made an anchor tag, I want to put Alike shortcode in href but It's not working.
You can see my code below, there is a anchor tag with `href="#"`, is there any solution?

```php
function wpb_demo_shortcode() {
    $html = '';
    $html .= '<div class="crypto-box">';

    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Crypto Brokers', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post();
            $html .= "<div class='crypto_content'>";
            $html .= "<div class='crypto_left'>";
            $html .= "<div class='crypto_img'>".get_the_post_thumbnail()."</div>";
            $html .= '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_field('review_button').'</a>';
            $html .= "</div>";
            $html .= "<div class='crypto_center'>";
            $html .= '<h4>'.get_the_title().'</h4>';
            $html .= "<p>".get_the_excerpt()."</p>";
            $html .= "</div>";
            $html .= "<div class='crypto_right'>";
            $html .= '<p><b>Location : </b>'.get_field('location').'</p>';
            $html .= '<p><b>Leverage : </b>'.get_field('leverage').'</p>';
            $html .= '<p><b>Deposit : </b>'.get_field('deposit').'</p>';
            $html .= '<p><b>Spreads : </b>'.get_field('spreads').'</p>';
            $html .= '<p><b>Instruments : </b>'.get_field('instruments').'</p>';
            $html .= '<p><b>Platforms : </b>'.get_field('platforms').'</p>';
            $html .= "</div>";
            $html .= '<a href="#" class="cp_btn">'.get_field('compare_button').'</a>';
            $html .= "</div>";
        };
        wp_reset_postdata();
    };
    $html .= '</div>';

    return $html;
}

// register shortcode
add_shortcode('crypto', 'wpb_demo_shortcode');
```

Comment: Can you fix the code embed? It should be 3 backticks on a line, then the code, then 3 backticks on a line to end the code block. At the moment every individual line is its own codeblock, with no indentation. Also note that 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic here, if any alike plugin knowledge is needed to understand or answer this question then it would be off topic and not in this stacks scope. I've fixed a little bit off the code formatting as an example, use the edit link to fix it so it's readable

Comment: thanks for the correction actually I am new here